# I need detail on how to make a button in an asp updatepanel that does NOT post back to the server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Basically, the button will open a dialog page to verify a license agreement then request a file from the user, by pathname only, but will not use that value to post or partial post the form for this point. I have tried numerous searches, but due to the negative logic, searches return false results as far as I have discovered. After the file is selected and the user is ready, the file selected is uploaded, and that could post, but the rest of the form content and validation must be excluded at that point, chrome is having it all go at once.

Comment: If you want to open a new page on button click, how do you plan on doing that without a postback? What page will be sent to your browser, and what server or application will know when to send it without a postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the simplest working answer is to write the href value that will be used before the asp creates one, by adding this property like so:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnBrowse" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:Preview(); return false;"
                            Style="background-image: url(../../App_Themes/Images/btn-browse.jpg); float: left;
                            margin-left: 5px" Width="85px" CssClass="LinkButton"  href="#"/>
```

the href property at the end set to # did the trick, before asp chose to give its own post code value to it. At least, thats how I currently understand it.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a button that doesn't post to the server, add a client-side click event handler that simply returns false. If it's an ASP.NET button, the syntax should be something like:

```
OnClientClick='ShowDialogPage(); return false'
```

Where ShowDialogPage is the JavaScript method you would use to show the dialog page without going to the server.

Be aware that everything the button does has to be possible in client-side code. If you're showing new content, that content must be available in the browser when the button is clicked, and not served after a subsequent request.

Comment: the return false piece was not working. as you will see in my working answer.